# subtracting from multiple variables at a time

Tags: python, variables, syntax-error

So recently I've ben interested in learning python, and I got the "Think python" last Christmas. Unfortunately I haven't had the time to really get into it because of my exams. Even though I the book was written for python 2 I decided to use python 3.4.3 anyway. This does however create a few problems. I have been able solve most of the problems by browsing the internet and whatnot, but this is one problem I haven't been able to find a solution for.

There's this exercise where I should practice python as a calculator to become familiar with it:

"opg.3 If I leave my house at 6:52 am and I run 1 mile at an easy pace (8:15 min per mile), then 3 miles at tempo (7:12 min per mile) and I run 1 mile at an easy pace again, what time do I get home for breakfast?"

For this exercise I wanted to create two variables, one called "hours" and one called "minutes". What is supposed to happen is that when the variable "minutes" >= 60, the variable "hours" should increase by 1 and "minutes" should decrease by 60.

```
hours = 6.0
minutes = 52.0
if minutes >= 60:
    hours += 1 and minutes -= 60



print ( )
print ( )
print ( )
print ( "opg.3---------------*" )
print ("minutes += 8.15*2 + 7.12*3")
        minutes += 8.15*2 + 7.12*3    
print ( "back home at",hours,":",minutes , "<<" )
print ( "--------------------*" )
print ( )
print ( )
print ( )
print ( )
```

There's two problems with my scrip.

The first problem happens here:

```
if minutes >= 60:
    hours += 1 and minutes -= 60
                            ^
                            |
```

That equal sign is according to python "invalid syntax" and I don't know why? what can I do to fix this?

Comment: in short, the `and` keyword looks for boolean operation, or `True`- and `False`-s. You have assignment (`hours += 1`), hence the problem (if you wanted to know _why_ the code didn't work) :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just move them to two separate lines

```
if minutes >= 60:
    hours += 1
    minutes -= 60
```

[From PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

> Compound statements (multiple statements on the same line) are generally discouraged.

For the sake of completeness, I will tell you that you can add `;` to terminate a statement, so you could've written

```
if minutes >= 60:
    hours += 1; minutes -= 60
```

But again I would discourage you from doing so. Just because you can, doesn't mean you should :)

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick answer :D I barely even got to finish my profile before seeing that you had answered.